Manual MLE of AR(1) yields a weird initial value $y_0$
I am playing with a manual implementation of the maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) of the parameters in an AR(1) model
$$
y_t = c + \varphi_1 y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t
$$
with $\text{Var}(\varepsilon_t)=\sigma^2$. I compare my results with those obtained by Arima from the forecast package (based on arima from the stats package).

My likelihood is slightly higher than that from Arima.
The estimates are not identical but fairly close, with the exception of the initial value $y_0$. My estimator delivers a value that seems too high (above the range of $y$) and is far away from the much more reasonable value from Arima.

I have tried a few different starting values for the manual MLE but got the same result every time.
What am I doing wrong?
library(fpp2) # needed for the example dataset

# Log-likelihood of AR(1)
loglik <- function(pars){
 c      <- pars["c"     ] # constant
 phi1   <- pars["phi1"  ] # slope
 sigma2 <- pars["sigma2"] # error variance
 y0     <- pars["y0"    ] # initial value of the time series
 T      <- length(y)
 e      <- rep(NA,T)
 e[1]   <- y[1] - ( c + phi1*y0 )
 for(t in 2:T){
  e[t]  <- y[t] - ( c + phi1*y[t-1] )
 }
 Li     <- dnorm(e, mean=0, sd=sqrt(sigma2))
 loglik <- sum(log(Li))
 return(loglik)
}

y <- diff(log(oil)) # annual % changes in oil production in Saudi Arabia 1966-2013

# Optimize the loglik function
opars <- c(c=0, phi1=0, sigma2=var(y), y0=mean(y)) # initial values for the parameters
#opt <- optim(par=opars, fn=loglik, method="BFGS", control=list(fnscale=-1)) # unbounded optimization
opt <- optim(par=opars, fn=loglik, method="L-BFGS-B", control=list(fnscale=-1), 
             lower=c(-Inf,-0.99,1e-10,-Inf), 
             upper=c( Inf, 0.99,Inf  , Inf)) # bounded optimization with -0.99<=phi1<=0.99 and 0<sigma2
opt$convergence # value of 0 indicates proper convergence of the optimization algorithm
optres <- c(opt$par, logL=opt$value) # main results in a single vector

# Compare to what `forecast::Arima` yields for the same data
m1      <- Arima(y, order=c(1,0,0), method="CSS-ML")
m1      <- Arima(y, order=c(1,0,0), method="ML"    )
chat    <- unname(m1$coef[2]*(1 - m1$coef[1])) # estimate of c expressed in terms of the estimate of mu
phi1hat <- unname(m1$coef[1])
y0hat   <- (y[1] - chat - m1$residuals[1]) / phi1hat # estimate of y0
m1par   <- c(c=chat, phi1=phi1hat, sigma2=m1$sigma2, y0=y0hat) 
m1res   <- c(m1par, logL=m1$loglik)   # main results in a single vector

# Print out and compare manual ML estimates with the ones from `Arima`
estimates <- rbind(optres,m1res)
rownames(estimates) <- c("Manual","Arima") 
print(round(estimates, digits=6))


I think that first observation $y_1$ should have mean $c$ and  variance $\sigma^2 / [1 - \phi_1^2]$, so $y_0$ is not a parameter.

@Yves, I want full MLE that takes into account the unobserved initial values (p of them for AR(p), thus 1 here) and treats them as parameters to be estimated. Does that make sense?

Since $y_0$ is not a parameter, you seem to use Expectation-Maximization? But then I would take  $y_0$ as set to its conditional expectation which depends on the parameter $[c,,\phi_1, ,\sigma^2]$ as well as on the observations.

@Yves, setting $y_0$ to a fixed value sounds like conditional MLE to me because, we are conditioning on this (unobserved) value. I thought my code was doing full, unconditional MLE. How do I do full, unconditional MLE then?

Since the model is stationary you can take the first observation as drawn from the stationary distribution, here a Gaussian with mean $c$ and variance $\sigma^2 /[1 - \phi^2]$. For a higher order AR(p) you should use a State-space representation.

Since I got your attention with the bounty, here are some other recent (and not so recent) questions of mine that have not been answered. Would you care taking a look? Your help will be appreciated.

@RichardHardy the initial value is not a model parameter. If you would generate an AR1 process with this stepwise procedure (creating $x_{n+1}$ based on $x_n$) then the initial value is drawn from a normal distributed.

I have a deleted answer because it doesn't match. One interesting aspect is that the arima model is not estimating the mean $c$ as part of the likelihood function, and instead uses the mean of the values instead.

@SextusEmpiricus, thank you! Why does it have to be so complicated?.. Perhaps there is a detailed explanation of how R's arima function works. It would be nice to get it.

I tried to look up the underlying code, but the c-function ARIMA_Like is written for efficiency and not for easy interpretability.

What is certain is that $c$ and $\sigma^2$ are based on $\varphi$ as you can compute it afterwards and they match the formula's. But when I manually fix them, then I still don't get the same likelihood.

I am actually surprised why the manual MLE wouldn't give an estimate for $c$ that equals the mean.

I haven't had much time to study the arima algorithms much further, but fwiw, the likelihood of stats::arima0 matches the likelihood of the manual method, and differs with forecast::Arima in not using a prior for the variance. Still the stats::arima0 does not end up with the same fit, because the variance is estimated separately. The method uses some sort of alternative state space where the likelihood is fit without considering the variance.

@SextusEmpiricus, thank you for your help! It would be a shame to waste a bounty, so if no better answers are posted in the next couple of days, I would like to award it to you. If you posted an answer with all the helpful bits of information you have provided so far, that would be fine. Of course, we still have these two days left, but I do not have high hopes...
