Likelihood from forecast::Arima vs. manual replication
I am trying to replicate some results from forecast::Arima in R. I am particularly interested in the likelihood that I would like to use for some likelihood ratio tests later on. (As noted in the comments, the question is really about stats::arima that is running in the background of forecast::Arima.)
Setup 1: i.i.d. data, very simple models
I simulate some i.i.d. data. I start with an MA(1) model estimated by forecast::Arima and stored as m0. I extract its log-likelihood and store it as logL0a. I extract its residuals e0 and the estimated error variance sigma20. I use the normal density with parameters 0 and sigma20 to obtain the likelihoods of the residuals and store them as Li0. I take the log and sum them up and store the log-likelihood as logL0b. I would expect logL0b = logL0b. The actual result is not far off (the third decimal is off, which is about $10^{-6}$ fraction of the log-likelihood).
I do the same for a SARIMA(0,0,1)(0,0,1)$_4$ model and end up with logL1b and logL1b. Again, logL1b = logL1b is a decent (?) approximation to my actual result (the third decimal is off).
Setup 2: i.i.d. data, more complex models
Things change when I go for larger models such as ARMA(2,2) instead of MA(1). The first decimal is off for the log-likelihoods, which is about $10^{-4}$ fraction of them.
Setup 3: data that follow SARIMA, more complex models
Things change even more when I go for SARIMA(2,0,2)(1,0,0)$_4$ data with the same models as in Setup 2. Now the differences between forecast::Arima and my "manual" replication of the log-likelihoods explodes up to double digits, or 1.2%. That looks like a major discrepancy to me.
Question
How should I modify my code to replicate the results from forecast::Arima (or really from stats::arima)?
#------------------------------ Setup 1

T <- 1e3
set.seed(12345); x <- rnorm(T) %>% ts(start=c(1900,1), frequency=4)

# Model 0
m0 <- x %>% Arima(order=c(0,0,1), seasonal=c(0,0,0)) 
# loglik directly from `forecast::Arima`:
logL0a <- m0$loglik # directly from `forecast::Arima`
# loglik by manual calculation:
e0 <- m0$residuals 
mu0 <- 0
sigma20 <- m0$sigma2 
Li0 <- dnorm(e0, mean=mu0, sd=sqrt(sigma20))
logL0a <- Li0 %>% log() %>% sum()

# Model 1
m1 <- x %>% Arima(order=c(0,0,1), seasonal=c(0,0,1))
# loglik directly from `forecast::Arima`:
logL1a <- m1$loglik
# loglik by manual calculation:
e1 <- m1$residuals 
mu1 <- 0
sigma21 <- m1$sigma2 
Li1 <- dnorm(e1, mean=mu1, sd=sqrt(sigma21))
logL1b <- Li1 %>% log() %>% sum()

# Print the results  

mat <- c(logL0a=logL0a, logL1a=logL1a, diffa=logL0a-logL1a, 
         logL0b=logL0b, logL1b=logL1b, diffb=logL0b-logL1b) %>% 
         matrix(nrow=2, byrow=TRUE) 
colnames(mat) <- c("logL0", "logL1", "diff")
rownames(mat) <- c("forecast::Arima", "Manual calculation") 
mat %>% round(digits=5) %>% print()

# Result: somewhat small difference in the log-likelihoods from 
# forecast::Arima vs. "manual".

#------------------------------ Setup 2

s <- 4 # seasonal frequency
m0 <- x %>% Arima(order=c(2    ,0,2    ), seasonal=c(1,0,1)); 
logL0a <- m0$loglik 
m1 <- x %>% Arima(order=c(2+1*s,0,2+1*s), seasonal=c(0,0,0)); 
logL1a <- m1$loglik
e0 <- m0$residuals; mu0 <- 0; sigma20 <- m0$sigma2; 
Li0 <- dnorm(e0, mean=mu0, sd=sqrt(sigma20)); 
logL0b <- Li0 %>% log() %>% sum()
e1 <- m1$residuals; mu1 <- 0; sigma21 <- m1$sigma2; 
Li1 <- dnorm(e1, mean=mu1, sd=sqrt(sigma21)); 
logL1b <- Li1 %>% log() %>% sum()

# Print the results  

mat <- c(logL0a=logL0a, logL1a=logL1a, diffa=logL0a-logL1a, 
         logL0b=logL0b, logL1b=logL1b, diffb=logL0b-logL1b) %>% 
         matrix(nrow=2, byrow=TRUE) 
colnames(mat) <- c("logL0", "logL1", "diff")
rownames(mat) <- c("forecast::Arima", "Manual calculation") 
mat %>% round(digits=5) %>% print()

# Result: medium difference in the log-likelihoods from 
# forecast::Arima vs. "manual".

#------------------------------ Setup 3

# Simulate a SARIMA(2, 0, 2)(1, 0, 1)_4 process manually

# First, set the parameter values
s <- 4        # seasonal frequency
c <- 0.1      # constant
phi1 <-  0.2; phi2 <- -0.4 # AR coefficients
the1 <- -0.4; the2 <-  0.6 # MA coefficients; `the` stands for `theta`
PHI1 <-  0.42 # seasonal AR coefficient
THE1 <-  0.3  # seasonal MA coefficient

# Second, simulate the process
set.seed(0); eps <- rnorm(T) # innovations
x <- eps
for(t in (s+3):T){ 
  x[t] <- c + phi1*x [t-1] + phi2*x [t-2] + PHI1*x [t-s] + 
          phi1*PHI1*x [t-(s+1)] + phi2*PHI1*x [t-(s+2)] + eps[t] + 
          the1*eps[t-1] + the2*eps[t-2] + THE1*eps[t-s] + 
          the1*THE1*eps[t-(s+1)] + the2*THE1*eps[t-(s+2)] 
} # SARMA(2,2)(1,1)_4

# Third, go up and run the entire Setup 2

# Result: large difference in the log-likelihoods from 
# forecast::Arima vs. "manual". 


Richard: For interest and learning, I'll put it all in R late tonight and try to see what's going on. But, I doubt that I'll end up being able to find the discrepancy. We shall see. Thanks for interesting problem.

This has nothing to do with the forecast package. loglik is computed by stats::arima.

Richard: I'm writing in the answer area because it's too long for a comment. Whether you want to check it or not, is up to you of course.
The general answer to your question is that, once you put the seasonal part into the model, there is code in stats::arima (Rob is correct; loglik is calculated by stats::arima) that changes what the arima function calls n.used. n.used accounts for the fact that  observations are lost when the seasonal part of the model is included. (It accounts for all the pieces, not just the seasonal. But the seasonal seems to be the most tricky.)
The formula that stats::arima uses for the log likelihood is
 -1/2 (2 * n.used * res$value + n.used + n.used * log(2 * pi))
so the dependence on n.used is explicit. The dependence of the number of observations on your loglik is more implicit because you sum over the length of the residuals. But obviously, the longer the length, the greater the sum. (Note that res$value is the objective function that was maximized in the optim call.)
Unless I made a function called myarima and ran the code in the R debugger (I've done things like that in the past sometimes with success and sometimes not), it's not possible for me to tell what the author, Brian Ripley (the author of at least most of it if not all), is doing with n.used. In fact, the code looks so hard-complex in that section that I doubt I would get very enlightened stepping through it in the browser() anyway.
To summarize, the difference is due to n.used being different from your n. This is due to the seasonal part of the model causing observations to be lost. I hope this helps some.

This is certainly interesting and helpful! If the main problem is indeed the first few observations, then the discrepancy in average likelihood (likelihood divided by the number of observations) should diminish with sample size. I will experiment with that. (SARIMA gets slow with large samples...)

Hi Richard: i'm not sure if they all get cut in the front but I would think so.  Also, the log likelihood contains a lot of constants that can confuse the issue ( I was trying to figure out how stats::arima came up with it's formula and I failed ) . All you really need to do is compare the length of your residuals with stats::arima's residuals. If their respective lengths are different, then you can back out n.used. Also, if you don't mind me asking, why do you need to match stats::arima's  loglik exactly ? I guess it would be nice but it doesn't seem necessary.

I want to build a likelihood ratio test. I am assuming that arima yields a log-likelihood that is correct up to a constant shift. Then the difference between two log-likelihoods will be correct (zero shift). But when doing it manually, my differences are not the same as these from arima, and I am wondering why. Your answer gives the reason.

that makes sense. and the difference in the number of observations used could make a difference in the values of the log likelihoods.  It's weird though right because $n.used + n.used \times log(2\pi)$ seems useless to me as far as there being data involved. In fact, there is no data involved so why should the log likelihood need those expressions. The LL is a representation of how well the data did. Yet, one needs to keep them in because if one is dividing by another likelihood, then taking them out would cause distortion in the ratio.

I am not really tempted to drop any terms from the likelihood, because it will just cause trouble whenever you need the actual likelihood. Having a couple of idle constants around should be negligible computationally.

yeah. it's best to have it exactly like R does it. But figuring out the right n.used every time, given the seasonal piece, may not be easy ? I guess you could compare the length of the residuals every time but that's seems like too much overhead.

In arima, the length of the residuals is the same as the length of the original time series regardless of the model.

I gotta go but that's odd. I would think that the length of the residuals in arima would have been the same as n.used. That's even a worse problem and not expected by me.

One aspect of a discrepancy in the log-likelihood computation, is that the true likelihood should not be based on identically distributed residuals.
This occurs also in an AR(1) model. We have that $x_{t} \sim N(\varphi x_{t-1}, \sigma^2)$, and residuals like $r_{t} = x_{t}-\phi x_{t-1}$ will be distributed as $N(0,\sigma^2)$. But, the first residual $r_1$ can not be computed as $x_{1}-\phi x_{0}$, will instead be expressed as $r_1 = x_1$ and has a larger variance.
Below is an example r-code that reproduces the error and corrects it by making two adjustments.

Use a different variance, the forecast package reports a bias corrected standard deviation which is not the value used to compute the likelihood
Treat the first starting values different. Computing the likelihood of variables with different variances is not the same when you standardize them to have equal variance. Somewhere under the hood the arima function performs the fitting correctly with non-standardized residuals, but in the output it uses standardized residuals.

library(fpp2)       # example data
y <- diff(log(oil)) # annual % changes in oil production in Saudi Arabia 1966-2013


### arima modelling
m1      <- forecast::Arima(y, order=c(1,0,0), include.mean = TRUE, 
                           method="ML" , transform.pars = FALSE, 
                           optim.method = "BFGS", optim.control=list(abstol=10^-15))


r = m1$residuals

### Variance
### the reported sigma/variance is corrected and not the MLE
# V = m1$sigma2 
V = m1$sigma2*(n-2)/n
sig = rep(V^0.5,length(r))

### The first observation
r[1] = r[1]/(1-m1$coef[1]^2)^0.5          ### undo the standardisation
sig[1] = sig[1]/(1-m1$coef[1]^2)^0.5  ### the first error term variance needs to be corrected

### now they are equal both 24.67388
m1$loglik 
sum(dnorm(r, 0 , sig, log = TRUE))
~~


This relates to your other question, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/648189 where I could eventually figure out how the likelihood is computed, but even then the optimization/fitting somehow results in a different MLE.

I would have loved to split the bounty over the two answers, but I cannot, so it goes to you who delivered the answer during the bounty period. Thank you!
